# Unable to access selected CheckBoxList Which is dynamically Created

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamically-generated

I have searched a lot and failed to and finally arrived here...

I am creating a checkboxList dynamically from the database successfully. Then I want to submit these selcted checked items, I am unable to access. Please find the code....

```
protected void CreateCheckBoxListDynamically()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection dBConnection = null;
    try
    {
        dBConnection = new SqlConnection();
        dBConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetDomesticCountryList", dBConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (ddlTournamentType.SelectedValue != "Select" && ddlTournamentType.SelectedValue != "")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TournamentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTournamentType.SelectedValue);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TournamentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;

        dBConnection.Open();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            CheckBoxList cblCountry = new CheckBoxList();
            cblCountry.ID = "cblCountryTeam";
            cblCountry.DataTextField = dt.Columns["CT_CountryTeamName"].ToString();
            cblCountry.DataValueField = dt.Columns["CT_CountryTeamId"].ToString();
            cblCountry.DataSource = dt;
            cblCountry.DataBind();

            //phCheckBoxList.Attributes.Add("class", "groupbox"); 
            phCheckBoxList.Controls.Add(cblCountry);
            phCheckBoxList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }

        dBConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close data reader object and database connection
        if (dBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            dBConnection.Close();
    }
}

protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlConnection dBConnection = new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    string countryTeamIds = "";
    try
    {
        dBConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString;

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_AddNewSeries", dBConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = memberId;

        if (ddlTournamentType.SelectedValue != "Select")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TournamentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTournamentType.SelectedValue);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TournamentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSeriesStartDate.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeriesStartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtSeriesStartDate.Text);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeriesStartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSeriesEndDate.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeriesEndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtSeriesEndDate.Text);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeriesEndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;

        // get values from dynamic controls
        CheckBoxList cb = (CheckBoxList)phCheckBoxList.FindControl("cblCountryTeam");
        if (cb != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in cb.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)
                    countryTeamIds += li.Value + "~";
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryTeamIds))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryTeamIds", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = countryTeamIds;
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryTeamIds", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;

        dBConnection.Open();

        dataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //hdnseriesId.Value = cmd.Parameters["@SeriesId"].Value.ToString();

        if (i == 0)
        {
            msgNoRecords.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            msgNoRecords.Visible = false;
            //Response.Redirect("~/country.aspx", false);
        }

        dBConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close data reader object and database connection
        cmd.Dispose();
        cmd = null;
        if (dBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            dBConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: no there is no error but I am getting CheckBoxList cb as null in button click event.

Answer (score 0):

As per you code details object phCheckBoxList has created in aspx page.
If i am right then this will create problem adding checkboxs at server side.

why dont you create only checkbox at server side rather than checkboxLIST. 
After creating checkbox you can add is `<div>`(this has to be declared at aspx page). this `<div>` should have an ID and make it `runat="server"` so you can get this.

After doing above task you can easy find every checkbox from that div at server side code.

Comment: Yes Darshan...It may be a nice approach to solve this but I don't know the exact number of checkbox controls. some times it may be morethan 50 that's why I chose checkboxList.

And yes you are right, I have created phCheckBoxList in aspx page.

Comment: ohh ok i think i got the exact problem can you call your method `CreateCheckBoxListDynamically()` at page load event also then try to access these controls it may help you.

Comment: actually CreateCheckBoxListDynamically() is based on another dropdown so i am calling it at dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged function....

Comment: Yes that is not a problem... you also need to call this pageload event too. because when you create dynamic control by default its viewstate property is false dute that you have to call from pageload too. for this you have to create one Viewstate variable as flag and make this variable true at selected index change event of dropdown and make it false on first time pageload that is under not IsPostback and also for ispostback call your method `CreateCheckBoxListDynamically()` if that ViewState flag property is true.. this will work..